# Why typescript typeguard doesn't work for an internal property of an object

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Using typescript, when a function returns an object that has properties that might be null. Why does using a typeguard on these inner properties not allow typescript to infer that the inner prop must not be null after the guard?

Here's a minimum example of this. [Try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHARnAzhAJQlwAcB7EfZAbwFgAoZZfMMUAc1wC5mwoPkAH2QgArgBtxDAL4NQkWIhQBZOKCKkKVOo2YRWHbr34h2MhgwRawyKPv4QAbhABiUMgFt0mHFQC8yAAUAJQ83th4hMTklCh%20AHw0DEx2YKJQIEm6TCxspkYA5HDiAO5wAJ64yHDGHAXJyLL0TZbWyB5qmQEhPKrq0VoowgCiUO5QyAlZTFaUNgAmGDUBqQ7Obp7hvhAhFrrAMEGLmAB0uYaTfgFiksHTTMhgABbuJSIQb6Pju7otuqnpTLHOAyIA)

```
interface DatabaseResponse {
  settings: string | null
}
interface MainResponse {
  settings: string
}

const retrieveFromDatabase = (): DatabaseResponse => {
  return {
    settings: 'always a string but lets pretend it could be null sometimes'
  }
}

const main = (): MainResponse | Error => {
  const data = retrieveFromDatabase()

  if (data.settings === null) {
    throw new Error()
  }

  return data

}
```

The error for the return of the main function is

```
Type 'DatabaseResponse' is not assignable to type 'MainResponse | Error'.
  Type 'DatabaseResponse' is not assignable to type 'MainResponse'.
    Types of property 'settings' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: This is a design limitation of TypeScript and possible feature request, see [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) for info and it might even make it into the language at some point (there's activity on [microsoft/TypeScript#38839](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38839) which would fix it)

Comment: Thanks for the info @jcatz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really a type guard. You can do this instead:

```
interface DatabaseResponse {
    settings: string | null
}
interface MainResponse {
    settings: string
}

const retrieveFromDatabase = (): DatabaseResponse => {
    return {
        settings: 'always a string but lets pretend it could be null sometimes'
    } as DatabaseResponse
}

const main = (): MainResponse | Error => {
    const data = retrieveFromDatabase()

    if (!isMainResponse(data)) {
        throw new Error()
    }

    return data
}

const isMainResponse = (data: DatabaseResponse | MainResponse): data is MainResponse {
  return !!data.settings;
}
```

Or similarly, create a new nonNullable type with the same typeguard

```
type NonNullableDB = { [K in keyof DatabaseResponse]: NonNullable<DatabaseResponse[K]> }

const isMainResponse = (data: DatabaseResponse | MainResponse): data is NonNullableDB => {
    return !!data.settings;
}
```

Comment: "That's not really a type guard".  It's true that the compiler doesn't guard the parent object type by checking its property (it only does that for discriminated unions, and `DatabaseResponse` isn't a union at all) as of TypeScript 4.1.  It might in the future though... see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384